# Displaying a message after registration in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS 13 app with a registration form. The API that i am integrating with requires users to validate their email after registration. What im trying to do is once the registration form is successful, remove the form fields and display a message that they need to check their email for a verification email, but instead it keeps redirecting to the login form. I am learning NextJS at the moment so the code i am using is from an example repo. Is it possible to change it to display a message instead of redirecting to login?

My register page looks like so;

```
'use client'

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

import { useUserService } from '@/app/_services'

export default Register

function Register() {
    const userService = useUserService()

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm()

    async function onSubmit(user) {
        await userService.register(user)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            >
                <div className="col-span-full">
                    <label
                        htmlFor="email"
                    >
                        Email address
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        { ...register("email") }
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-full">
                    <label
                        htmlFor="password"
                    >
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        { ...register("password") }
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-full pt-5">
                    <button
                        disabled={formState.isSubmitting}
                    >
                        <span>Register</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

The actual register function is located in the `useUserService` file and has the following details;

```
register: async (user) => {
    alertService.clear()

    try {
        await fetch.post('/api/authentication/register', user);

        router.push('/login');
    } catch (error) {
        alertService.error(error);
    }
},
```

Comment: it keep redirecting to login form because you are doing that by router.push('/login'). You need to comment this line and show the message to user for email.